# Making Android Peripheral and iPhone as Central in Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

I could able to broadcast the packets , iPhone is able to discover the services hosted in android phone. But not able to Read or Write . Anybody knows about it, why it is happening like that ??

Comment: Could you be more specific? and maybe show your code too? that would help us to find you a solution

Comment: As above, please post some code. Are you using a standard Gatt Profile? If not, are your characteristics set up properly, as they can be configured as Read or Write or Read/Write. You can use `Light Blue` iOS app to interrogate the service and see details on the service, it's characteristics and their properties.